# BaseType of a Basetype

Tags: c#

this is my first question here so I hope I can articulate it well and hopefully it won't be too mind-numbingly easy.

I have the following class *SubSim* which extends *Sim*, which is extending *MainSim*. In a completely separate class (and library as well) I need to check if an object being passed through is a type of *MainSim*. So the following is done to check;

```
Type t = GetType(sim);
//in this case, sim = SubSim
if (t != null)
{
  return t.BaseType == typeof(MainSim);
}
```

Obviously *t.BaseType* is going to return *Sim* since *Type.BaseType* gets the type from which the current Type directly inherits.

Short of having to do *t.BaseType.BaseType* to get *MainSub*, is there any other way to get the proper type using .NET libraries? Or are there overrides that can be redefined to return the main class?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are 4 related standard ways:

```
sim is MainSim;
(sim as MainSim) != null;
sim.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(MainSim));
typeof(MainSim).IsAssignableFrom(sim.GetType());
```

You can also create a recursive method:

```
bool IsMainSimType(Type t)
 { if (t == typeof(MainSim)) return true;   
   if (t == typeof(object) ) return false;
   return IsMainSimType(t.BaseType);
 }
```

Comment: I like that recursive method, and I think I'm going to try that instead of my solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

```
if (sim is MainSim)
```

is all you need. "is" looks up the inheritance tree.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`is` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(VS.71).aspx):

```
return t is MainSim;
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'is' option didn't work for me. It gave me the warning; "The given expression is never of the provided ('MainSim') type", I do believe however, the warning had more to do with the framework we have in place. My solution ended up being:

```
return t.BaseType == typeof(MainSim) || t.BaseType.IsSubclassof(typeof(MainSim));
```

Not as clean as I'd hoped, or as straightforward as your answers seemed. Regardless, thank you everyone for your answers. The simplicity of them makes me realize I have much to learn.

Comment: You probably did "return t is MainSim" instead of "return sim is MainSim".

Comment: Initially I did try that, What I left out of my question is that the object 'sim' would be a CollectionRow object, not necessarily a Sim object per se, that is why there is the call Type t = GetType(sim). I tried a couple of other things but it was returning false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

How about "is"?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(VS.71).aspx